# Pale render view

Tags: rendering

I am new to Blender and having problems figuring out what I did making the render view pale. I remembered the original viewport is a dark one. I removed all the lights but it seems to have nothing to do with lighting.

[image]

Here is my file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ukCW8k1GjAS3Xndp3VrstnOSzBQfyfTO/view?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and post an image of the issue.

Comment: You might be in the 2d animation workspace. If you go to the top of the window, there should be a tab that says "Default" or similar. Click that and you should go back to the default workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color of your background is white. Bring it back to the color you want (or decrease the *Strength* down to 0). Also, in Eevee, I'm not sure that you can disable the *World*'s influence on the scene.

[image]